# Android Navigation Component (nav-graph) issues with Gradle 3.5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

I updated my Android Studio version to 3.5 and gradle to 3.5.0 without updating the gradle wrapper from 5.1.1 to 5.4.1 -- The issue that is raised is an Android Manifest tag (`<nav-graph>`) produces element is not allowed here.

Here's my manifest structure:

```
<application>
<activity
    android:name=".AuthenticationActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Auth"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.company.product.module.AuthenticationActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/navigation_activity_authentication" />
</activity>
```

I'm using a module-based project if that helps in troubleshooting the issue.

Here's the error:

```
AAPT: error: unexpected element <nav-graph> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using nav-graph and it's not mentioned in the Manifest file. And I haven't seen it being used in the Manifest file in the documentation. 
You just added to your fragment with:
    `app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_courses"`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

"The fix for this will be in 3.7 Canary 2 and 3.6 Beta 2"
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140856013

Answer (score 0):

I had this is issue too, on android studio 3.5.3. the problem was : I had multi-module project and my app module and main activity's module that contains nav host was not the same. Moving main activity with `nav-graph` tag to application module (Runner module) fixed my problem. e.g :

Module A (Phone & Table module) -> main module

Module B ( Android Library ) -> contains main activity with nav-graph
I moved the activity to module A and done.